# What happens when we reload Elixir modules?

Tags: elixir

I am adding spec information to my Elixir library but I noticed that when I reloaded the library in another IEx session, it did not pick up the '@spec' changes that I am adding. My question is, when we do

```
r(Module)
```

in IEx what exactly is being reloaded ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very good question!

When we reload the module in IEx, we recompile the module source code, reloading its contents in memory. The original .beam file in disk, probably the one where the first definition of the module came from, does not change at all.

Since typespecs and docs are loaded from the .beam file (they are not loaded in memory with the module because there is no need for them to be in memory), they are not updated when you reload the module because the contents in disk are still the same.

PS: I have answered mostly how the r/1 function works and why you are seeing this behaviour. If interested, you can read more about hot code swapping in general in Erlang which also applies to Elixir: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/designing-a-concurrent-application#hot-code-loving